# Cases Not Individually Named When Running SpockFramework Tests in Gradle Project with "Where"

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, spock

When running tests from Intellij or on commandline via gradle, the test cases for a where clause are not broken out and named

```
    final static String artifact = 'artifact'
    final static String version = '1.2.3'

    def getLayoutSpecificPathHappyPath(
         def platform, def expected) {
        given:
        when:
        def result = artifactoryManager.getLayoutSpecificPath(
                         platform, artifact, version)

        then:
        result == expected

        where:
        platform | prefix        | expected
        'npm'    | 'prefix'      | "${artifact}/-"
        'maven'  | 'prefix'      | "${artifact}/${version}"
```

*Result*

```
ArtifactoryManagerTest > getLayoutSpecificPathv2HappyPath FAILED
```

I think I've got a setting in my gradle file that is preventing printing of the case data making it easier to see which of the where's failed.

Comment: Which version of Spock are you using? In latest versions data driven test are unrolled by default unless you change tat. In older versions you have to do it manually or use the global unroll pluing that does it for all data driven tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the detail by setting the `displayGranularity` in [TestLogging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogging.html) and enabling the logging of relevant events.

> The display granularity of the events to be logged. For example, if set to 0, a method-level event will be displayed as "Test Run > Test Worker x > org.SomeClass > org.someMethod". If set to 2, the same event will be displayed as "org.someClass > org.someMethod".

```kotlin
tasks.test {
    testLogging {
        events ("passed", "skipped", "failed")
        displayGranularity = 1
    }
}
```