# Gradle: How to change test result output

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spock

By default, when executing `gradle test`, the output looks as such:

```
ExampleSpec > get all examples PASSED
```

If I remember correctly, back in the early days of Gradle the class would have the package name prepended. Hence you'd get a result more akin to:

```
com.company.ExampleSpec > get all examples PASSED
```

Is there any way to change how Gradle logs the finished tests to show the package name for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearest I could find was the following alteration to the gradle `Test` task:

```
String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m"
String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m"
String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m"
String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "failed"
        showExceptions true
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
    afterTest { TestDescriptor descriptor, TestResult result ->
        if(result.failedTestCount > 0) {
            println "${descriptor.className} > ${descriptor.name} ${ANSI_RED}FAILED${ANSI_RESET}"
        } else if(result.skippedTestCount > 0) {
            println "${descriptor.className} > ${descriptor.name} ${ANSI_YELLOW}SKIPPED${ANSI_RESET}"
        } else {
            println "${descriptor.className} > ${descriptor.name} ${ANSI_GREEN}PASSED${ANSI_RESET}"
        }
    }
}
```

It results in a slight bit of redundancy in the event of a test failure, but that way it will still emit a stack trace to assist the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76946372/2145769

You can control the detail by setting the `displayGranularity` in [TestLogging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogging.html) and enabling the logging of relevant events.

> The display granularity of the events to be logged. For example, if set to 0, a method-level event will be displayed as "Test Run > Test Worker x > org.SomeClass > org.someMethod". If set to 2, the same event will be displayed as "org.someClass > org.someMethod".

```kotlin
tasks.test {
    testLogging {
        events ("passed", "skipped", "failed")
        displayGranularity = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately. It still only prints the simple class name, not its canonical form. The only change is that it now includes which test executor is running the test, e.g. `Gradle Test Executor 2 > ExampleSpec > get all examples PASSED`. I tried all possible values for displayGranularity but none emit the canonical class name.